# Looking for a php blog engine/plugin for section on website

Tags: php, blogs, blog-engine

I'm looking to make one section on a website a blog and looking for suggestions on what's best to use.  I'm not interested in a complete website/cms package like wordpress, I just want something to handle the backend (preferably php/mysql based) to keep track of posts, comments, users, and handle feeds, etc.

The rest of the website is using php includes, so what I really want to be able to do is just include("blog.php"); and have it return a list of teasers, to click through for full article.  A tag list would be useful as well.

Anything around like this or am I going to have to write it myself or use wordpress or similar?

Answer (score 1):

I can understand the desire for something smaller, but when it comes to a full-fledged back-end, handling comments, users, feeds.... There are few products that can compete with WP.

It is possible to fetch lists of WP posts, categories, posts, and comments from within any PHP script, and display them in a custom fashion. Either in pure PHP by including the WordPress header include file, or by using its JSON or RSS export facilities.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055725) shows some approaches.

Comment: In my experience with WordPress it's a very self-centered script. I had a fully functional website up, I extracted the basic WordPress installation zip to my webroot (hoping it would play happily with my forum, imageboard, chat, etc.) and it had its own .htaccess that redirected EVERYTHING to its own index.php for parsing. I wouldn't suggest WordPress as a supplement to an existing project unless you already have sufficient experience with both PHP and WordPress and you feel you could integrate it nicely.

Comment: @steven running WP alongside another script is no problem at all, as long as you banish WP into a sub-directory (It is, as you say, very self-centered when allowed to have its way and installed in the web root, that much is true.). If necessary, you can fetch all content from a WP post into a custom web site using the Codex functions, without showing anything WP specific to the user

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I have built a website around a custom theme before (which to be honest I hated doing!) but I didn't realise it was that easy to just pull the posts.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: @steven that's what I don't like about wordpress as well but as @Pekka says, sticking it a subdirectory and disregarding half of the features does look like an option, if somewhat overkill.

Comment: I only like using wordpress to be and blog and that's it. However for a blog, I would suggest making your own setup, however when you do, bundle your code up so it can be a reusage plugin for any website you do. All a blog is doing is posting to a database and retrieving the information to be displayed when a user views it on your website.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious ansers are:

WordPress
LifeType
b2evolution
Pixelpost
Nucleus

I have hostgator with quick install in cPanel and you can have the up and running for testing if it is what you need in seconds (with Quick intall).

other options are (got them from sourceforge):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/evocms/
or
/projects/sphpblog/

I hop you find this usefull.

BTW if you search blog in sourceforge and the select PHP you´ll get endless options!

Trufa

Ps (I´m a newbie here cant post more than on hyperlink)